# Distribute small number of points on a disc

Tags: geometry, optimization

Firstly I strongly know how many similar questions there are here.
It's about sets of evenly distributed points inside a circle.
If we need a big set of such points, good solutions are:

- [Isocell method](http://orbi.ulg.ac.be/bitstream/2268/91953/1/masset_isocell_orbi.pdf); [Geogebra example](http://tube.geogebra.org/material/show/id/286087)
- [Spirales method](http://blog.marmakoide.org/?p=1); [Geogebra example](http://tube.geogebra.org/material/show/id/286063)

But it's interesting for me: 
if we have *small number of points*: 2,3,7,..
*what is "the most" even configuration
and what is the optimization criterion to find it?*

It seems that such configuration

[image]

is good for two points. But what about 5 points:

[image]

First or second?

I've been testing different optimizations: by area, by sum and variance of distances,
using Voronoi diagram etc. 
but not advanced further intuitive considerations.

Comment: Interesting! I would consider the Euclidean length squared between each point (x, y) and the nearest red dot, and average this over all the points (x , y) in the circle. Minimizing this quantity should be a fair optimization criterion.

Comment: In your 5-point example, I clearly prefer the first configuration. The second one feels unevenly distributed, since it leaves the centre too open, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it today!

Comment: As you are aware, there are many possible optimization criteria, and they may yield different optimal configurations. It's not possible to say which one is "the best"; different criteria will be useful for different purposes.

Comment: Well I'll be glad to see some examples! But it seems for request "even distribution" there is only one intelligent and meaningful criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have set of several points $Set$ and some net $Net$, $Size[Net] \gg Size[Set]$
 covered unit disc.
On the greate advice of M. Wind  let's calculate value (GeoGebra code, intuitive clear):

```
s = Mean[
        Zip[
              Distance[p, ClosestPoint[Set, p]]
        , p, Net]
        ]
```

and *try to minimize it, changing configuration of $Set$*.

I've done many experiments with GeoGebra applets. First conclusion is:
*All the results are independent from kind of $Net$ (isocell, spiral, random etc.)

if $Size[Net]$ is big enough.*

First question is:
*Is there another interesting and non-trivial optimization value?*
I've tried

```
s = Mean[
        Zip[
              Mean[
                       Zip[
                            Distance[p, ps]
                       ,ps,Set]
        , p, Net]
        ]
```

and some others. Method of M. Wind for now is the only effective and meanfull.

So came the turn of Wolfram Mathematica. After many intuitive attempts 
next results were obtained:

1. Using "brutal force" of Mathematica optimization utilites (NMinimize[], e.g. Method -> {"NelderMead", "ShrinkRatio" -> 0.99,  "ContractRatio" -> 0.99, "ReflectRatio" -> 2})
   one can get first approximations of distributes several points on a disc:

[image]

2. I propose the hypothesis that 
   **any optimal configuration consists of several regular polygons, rotated relative to one another.**
   And we may optimize not points of $Set$, but radii and angles of rotation that is much faster and better.

   Here is good example. Let $Size[Set]$=32. Here are four kind of sets:

   - Spiral 32-net; s = 0.12649
   - Isocell 32-net; s = 0.122737
   - Direct optimization of configuration of 32 points on disc; s = 0.121151
   - Smart optimization with manual selection of regular 
      polygons and numbers of vertices;
     **s = 0.120646**

[image]

So I think the last attempt is a real method of the most uniform and symetrical distribution any number of points on a disc.