# Equiareal Voronoi tessellation

Tags: area, tessellations

I'm interested in even (or "proportional") disrtributions of points on 2D areas.
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021272/distribute-small-number-of-points-on-a-disc) is the initial question, but many others ideas appeared later.

[Centroidal Voronoi tessellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroidal_Voronoi_tessellation) is well known construction.
But what about *equiareal Voronoi tessellation*, so areas of all cells are equal?
Using Mathematica there is no problem to find (numerically!) some example.

[image]

*Is there some general algorythm for equiareal tessellation of plane figures,
especially with Voronoi diagrams?*